Dependence in ARCH empirical residuals
Suppose $R_1, R_2, \dots, R_T$ are observed values of ARCH(1) process ($R_i = \sigma_i z_i$). I then estimate ARCH(1) parameters $\hat{\omega}, \hat{\alpha}$ and calculate empirical standardized residuals as
$$\hat{z}_i = \frac{R_i}{\hat{\sigma}_i},$$
where $\hat{\sigma}^2_i = \hat{\omega} + \hat{\alpha} R^2_{i-1}$. This empirical standardized residuals are obviously NOT independent. However, when $T$ grows they are "more and more" independent.
I am interested in formalization of this property of empirical standardized residuals. For example, I would like to say that $\hat{z}_1, \hat{z}_2, \dots, \hat{z}_T$ is a $\beta$-mixing sequence. Unfortunately, I was not able to find any materials on this topic.

It would be more precise to call the $\hat z_i$ (empirical) standardized residuals.

@RichardHardy, thanks for the note, reflected in the question
